# What does it mean to believe, faith, trust and confidence?

Tags: grammar, faith, definition

Whenever I look up dictionary definitions for faith it says faith means to trust I look up definition for trust it means confidence...the definition of confidence says trust or faith...the definition of believe is trust. What is the real definition? From what I understand believe means to accept as true. So we go to heaven based on what we accept as true? Going to heaven (salvation/eternal life) is based on accepting a truth then?

Comment: Yes, faith is essentially trust, but in a sense both answers are right. The usage in John's gospel varies betewen believing THAT (a statement is true) and believing IN (trusting a person),

Comment: @StephenDisraeli please don't forget to Vote to Close off topic Questions

Answer (score 1):

Faith is essentially trust.  (cf. He 11:1; Eph 3:12; Ro 4:19-21.)

In the Old Testament, we have the verb, "הֶאֱמִין" (from which we get the word, "amen" in English).  As the word is used (in the Hiphil here) it means being able to put your weight on someone/something and have it support you.  (BDB, s.v. “‏אָמַן,” 53.). In English then, the best word we have for that is "trust."

In the New Testament, we have the word, "πιστεύω".  The venerable lexicon, BDAG gives this as the definition:

> 1. to consider someth. to be true and therefore worthy of one’s trust, believe
>    a. believe (in) someth., be convinced of someth., w.
>    that which one believes (in) indicated. (BDAG, s.v. “πιστεύω,” 816.)

Hence, "trust" in English is a good fit for the word.

Finally, we note that believing (having faith) is not making a decision/choosing. the Greek has an entirely different word for that (ἐκλέγομαι).

To address your next point ("how do we get to heaven"), we note that, in all the times the Bible speaks of faith (esp. in the NT), we do not find the phrase, "because of faith" (δια πιστιν). Instead, it's "through/by faith" (δια πιστεως). Faith is a gift given to us by our Triune God through his word (1 Pet. 1:23; James 1:17-18; Rom. 10:17, et al.). Our faith links/connects us to Jesus (and through that, into heaven). Our faith is a gift given from God (through his word), not a good work we offer up to God.